# In Vim why is the behavior of "w" word selector inconsistent when preceded by "d" vs "v"

Tags: vim

I'm wondering why in Vim the <kbd>w</kbd> key affects an inconsistent amount of text when preceded by <kbd>d</kbd> vs <kbd>v</kbd>. For example, suppose my cursor is over the "`t`" of "`two`" in this text:

```
one two three
```

Now <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> produces:

```
one three
```

But <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> produces:

```
one hree
```

Is there some setting to make this more consistent, or do I need to write my own custom definition to fix it?

Also, the capital <kbd>W</kbd> selector is similarly inconsistent, and I'm wondering if there's a key for visually selecting the same portion that <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> would have deleted?  Best I can come up with is <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> which is OK but wondered if there's anything shorter I'm missing that's built in.

Comment: It moves the cursor to the beginning of the next word; Visual mode isn’t only used for deleting. So it’s consistent in some way.

Comment: @Ry- Why `vwd` delets the first charachter if in the vimtutor it says that it EXCLUDES the first characther?

Comment: @Anton Visual mode includes the character the cursor is on.

Comment: @Ry- Apologize for my misunderstanding. Thank you. I set the motion to exclusive in order to be consistent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

yes there is one option: `selection` which default is `inclusive`. it makes `v` to select the last char.

```
:h 'selection'
```

to check detail.

`w` is exclusive motion.  but if in visual mode, it depends on the `selection` setting.

you could set `selection` to `exclusive` to make `vwd` and `dw` to behave identical.

Answer (score 5):

The `w` key does the same in both cases, it puts the cursor in the begining of the next word.

What is "inconsistent" is the `v` command.

In the first case `dw` means, delete up to, but not including, the cursor.

In the second case `vwd` deletes the selection, however the selection includes the cursor. You can clearly see this when you do `vw`.